# How to add or insert ' (single quotes) at begining and ' at ending of string

Tags: apex, class

My requirement is  to add single quotes at begining and end of the string.

Thanx

Comment: If your problem is around escaping single quotes then this should solve your issue: **String newString = '\''+ oldString + '\'';**

Comment: Thanx   @karthikselvakumar it work fine.. :)

Comment: From here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error Check to make sure that your question has the following:
A clear title.
A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
**Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.**
Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your problem is around escaping single quotes then this should solve your issue:

```
          String newString = '\''+ oldString + '\'';
```